# How to show dialog to send email AND call phone number in Android?

Tags: android

I am wondering if there is a way to have a "contact" button in Android and when the button is pressed a menu pops up giving you the possibility:

- to send an email (showing all available email accounts, send-to is a predefined email address
- or to call a predefined phone number

This should everything be in the same menu, so similar to this but also with the option to place a call:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-email-intent/ (sorry, as a new user I cannot post images yet...)

Is there a pre-defined function to do this or do I have to code the whole menu from scratch?

Thanks for your help,

Reto

Comment: Use [context menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) for this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, I have to build this up with a context menu. There is not a pre-defined thing similar to "Intent.createChooser(emailIntent..." which does support email and phone number and does display the icons, etc. And this also means I have to do it in two steps. First step show a context menu to ask whether the user wants to send an email or place a call and if he chooses email show the different email accounts... :-/